# spring repository cannot findbyemail

Tags: java, spring, repository

I have an entity class User

```
@Entity
public class User implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
}
```

on my UserDao i can successfully call method **User findByName(String name)** that returns:

```
 {
"id": 8,
"name": "roronoa zoro",
"email": "zoro@sunnygo.com"
 }
```

but always failed when calling this method **User findByEmail(String email)**.
i'm passing "zoro@sunnygo.com" as param, and got null.

then i tried **User findByEmailContaining(String email)** and it works, why can't I use **findByEmail** instead?

thanks in advance.

Comment: any errors in the log?

Comment: Can you add the spring data repository interface for User?

Comment: @ScaryWombat no error, just got null record.

Comment: @uday 
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer>{

 List<User> findAll();
 
 User findByEmail(String email);
}

Comment: is email a unique key in the DB, if not then maybe should return `List<User>`

Comment: @ScaryWombat yes, it's unique.

Comment: I don't see any problem with the code. Can you check if the email in database has leading or trailing spaces?

Comment: i've found the problem. i forgot to mention that i'm using REST to call the method using GET method, and I pass the param with @PathVariable so the email characters "zoro@sunnygo.com" not fully sent. it's only "zoro@sunnygo" sent to UserService. my bad.
thx guys..

Answer (score 1):

Probably too late an answer but if anyone else has a similar issue, it might be because you are passing the email as a url parameter using requestmapping on your rest controller, so the variable would be received as zoro@sunnygo rather than zoro@sunnygo.com. To solve this just change `@RequestMapping(value = "/get/{email}", method = RequestMethod.GET)` to `@RequestMapping(value = "/get/{email:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)`